# How to determine programmatically if an expression is rvalue or lvalue in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue, rvalue

What's the best way to determine if an expression is a rvalue or lvalue in C++? Probably, this is not useful in practice but since I am learning rvalues and lvalues I thought it would be nice to have a function `is_lvalue` which returns true if the expression passed in input is a lvalue and false otherwise.

Example:

```
std::string a("Hello");
is_lvalue(std::string()); // false
is_lvalue(a); // true
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Most of the work is already done for you by the stdlib, you just need a function wrapper:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_lvalue(T&&) {
  return std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{};
}
```

in the case you pass a `std::string` lvalue then `T` will deduce to `std::string&` or `const std::string&`, for rvalues it will deduce to `std::string`

Note that [Yakk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36312021/1013719) will return a different type, which allows for more flexibility and you should read that answer and probably use it instead.

Answer (score 30):

I solved the above question using two overloaded template functions. The first takes as input a reference to a lvalue and return `true`. Whereas the second function uses a reference to rvalue. Then I let the compiler match the correct function depending on the expression passed as input.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_lvalue(T&) {
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_lvalue(T&&) {
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::string a = std::string("Hello");
    std::cout << "Is lValue ? " << '\n';
    std::cout << "std::string() : " << is_lvalue(std::string()) << '\n';
    std::cout << "a : " << is_lvalue(a) << '\n';
    std::cout << "a+b : " << is_lvalue(a+ std::string(" world!!! ")) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Is Lvalue ? 
std::string() : 0
a : 1
a+b : 0
```

Comment: Since the parameters are unused, you should mark both functions as `constexpr` as the type is always known at compile-time

Comment: @RyanHaining Very true. Thank you for suggestion

Comment: Me, I'd return `std::true_type` and `false_type` for even more certainty.

Comment: @Yakk Thanks for the suggestion. I'll do it.

Comment: @Yakk What's the advantage of using `std::true_type` in this case?

Comment: @GiuseppePes It moves the compile-time-ness of the result into the type system, which lets you do things like pass it to a template function and certainly propogate its value.  At the same time, true type has a constexpr operator bool, so it can also be used in that context.

Comment: Technically speaking, you're really making an overload for lvalue references and forwarding references, and the compiler is just selecting the better match.

Answer (score 21):

I would take a page from `boost::hana` and make the return value of `is_lvalue` encode the lvalue-ness of its argument *both* as a `constexpr` value, *and* as a type.

This lets you do stuff like tag dispatching without extra boilerplate.

```
template<class T>
constexpr std::is_lvalue_reference<T&&>
is_lvalue(T&&){return {};}
```

the body of this function does nothing, and the parameter's value is ignored.  This lets it be constexpr even on non-constexpr values.

An advantage of this technique can be seen here:

```
void tag_dispatch( std::true_type ) {
  std::cout << "true_type!\n";
}
void tag_dispatch( std::false_type ) {
  std::cout << "not true, not true, shame on you\n";
}

tag_dispatch( is_lvalue( 3 ) );
```

Not only is the return value of `is_lvalue` available in a `constexpr` context (as `true_type` and `false_type` have a `constexpr operator bool`), but we can easily pick an overload based on its state.

Another advantage is that it makes it hard for the compiler to *not* inline the result.  With a `constexpr` value, the compiler can 'easily' forget that it is a true constant; with a type, it has to be first converted to `bool` for the possibility of it being forgotten to happen.

Comment: Any reason for `<T&&> ` and not `<T>`?

Comment: @RyanHaining Better error message?  `is_lvalue_reference<Foo&&>` seems clearer than `is_lvalue_reference<Foo>` in an overload resolution failure would be clearer to me.

Comment: @Barry The answers where good enough, so I suggested an improvement.  Nobody took it and ran with it, so I posted my improved version, together with an explanation why it is marginally better.

Comment: @Yakk This is C++. We're *all about* marginally better here.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`std::is_lvalue_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_lvalue_reference) and [`std::is_rvalue_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_rvalue_reference).

You don't need a wrapper if you're happy with using decltype.

```
std::string a("Hello");
std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype((std::string()))>::value; // false
std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype((a))>::value; // true
```

In C++17 you'll be able to use the following:

```
std::string a("Hello");
std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype((std::string()))>; // false
std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype((a))>; // true
```

Or you could write a wrapper as @Ryan Haining suggests, just make sure you get the types correct.