# Is constructed string("Plain Old C chain") a rvalue?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if a copy elision is made in the call of `foo(string)` below.
(Note: `foo(string)` belongs to an interface that I can not change).

For this I attempted to check whether constructed `string("Hello world!")` is a `rvalue`.

I searched on SO how to do this programmatically and found this post: [How to determine programmatically if an expression is rvalue or lvalue in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296425/how-to-determine-programmatically-if-an-expression-is-rvalue-or-lvalue-in-c)

```
void foo( string str)
{
    cout << str << endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo("Hello world!");
    cout << is_rvalue_reference<decltype(string("Hello world!"))>::value  << endl;
}
```

result is

```
Hello world!
0
```

I thought I would get `true` to `is_rvalue_reference< xxx >::value`

- Where am I wrong?
- `string("Hello world!")` may be a `rvalue` but does not seem to be a "reference of any kind" (either `lvalue`, `rvalue`, universal ... ) so that I got `false` result. Is there a way to get a `true` answer in case of a `rvalue`?
- Is there copy elision or not in his example?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> - Where am I wrong?

`std::string("")` is an rvalue, but `decltype(std::string(""))` is not an rvalue reference. The type of a `std::string` object is ... `std::string`, of course.

You have a category error. An rvalue is a kind of expression, an rvalue reference is a kind of type.

A temporary `string` object is an rvalue. The type `string&&` is an rvalue reference type.

Your `decltype` expression is not useful for what you're trying to do. Consider:

```
std::string s;
using type1 = decltype(s);
using type2 = decltype(std::string(""));
static_assert(std::is_same<type1, type2>::value, "same");
```

In both these cases `decltype` gives the same type: `std::string`. That's because `decltype` tells you about types, not value categories (i.e. whether an expression is an rvalue or an lvalue).

If you want to know whether an expression is an rvalue or an lvalue you need to know more than just its type. In the case of `decltype(std::string(""))` you are creating an unnamed temporary, which is an rvalue. You don't need to ask its type to know that.

> - *string("Hello world!")* may be a rvalue but does not seem to be a "reference of any kind" (either lvalue, rvalue, universal ... ) so that I got **false** result. Is there a way to get a *true* answer in case of a rvalue ?

What do you mean by "true" answer? Do you just mean a type trait that will give the result `true`?

You can ask if the type is convertible to an rvalue reference:

```
std::is_convertible<decltype(std::string("")), std::string&&>::value
```

That will tell you if you can bind an rvalue reference to the object. But it's a silly question: of course you can bind an rvalue reference of type X&& to a temporary of type X. You would never need to ask that.

And anyway, you function doesn't take an argument of type `string&&` so asking that question doesn't even tell you anything about your call to `foo(std::string)`.

> - Is there copy elision or not in his example ?

Yes, initializing the function argument from a temporary string should not make any copies or moves, they should be elided. The C++14 standard says in [class.copy] p31 that a copy/move can be elided when a temporary object (that has not been bound to a reference) would be copied/moved to a class object of the same type. That condition is met when initializing a function argument of class type from a temporary of the same type. A compiler that doesn't perform that elision (at least when optimisations are enabled, or in "release" builds) is a bad compiler.

There is an explanation of the copy elision rules at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision -- see the part about a nameless temporary.

Comment: Could you add a standard quote for the *copy elision* paragraph? I cannot  find a suitable one in [class.copy.elision].

Comment: _"Yes, initializing the function argument from a temporary string should not make any copies or moves, they should be elided."_ Only as of the as-yet-unpublished C++17, no? Sure in practice we'd expect elision but that's not the same thing as implying a standard mandate with the term "should".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, [no](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7712d5169881a3e1). The standard says when elision is allowed (and it's not allowed elsewhere, or that would be a non-conforming implementation). A compiler **should** elide wherever possible. Not all compilers do that. GCC, Clang and Intel all elide for the linked example.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Allowed to != Required to. And I'm not sure why you provided an example of elision in action; I already said we would expect it to occur in practice.

Comment: Which is why I said "should not". Not "will not". I meant exactly what I wrote.

Comment: I'm suggesting that readers could misread your "should" for something else, because in English it carries the sense of a _requirement_. I'm trying to help you get your point across as clearly as possible.

Comment: Then write your own answer. The question was "Is there copy elision or not" and my coliru demo shows there **is**. I said there **should be** elision, which is consistent with accepted specification writing to mean something to be expected, but not required. The word "should" does **not** imply something mandated by the standard, it has a specific meaning in ISO (and other) standards.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, C++14 12.8 [class.copy] p31 third bullet.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, since copy elision is never required in C++14, it's redundant to say "there is elision here, except maybe not depending on your compiler". That's implied in any discussion of copy elision prior to C++17. Copy elision in C++ today means something that is allowed but not required **by definition**.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, also C++14 5.2.2 [expr.call] p4 "During the initialization of a parameter, an implementation may avoid the construction of extra temporaries [...]". Don't look in the C++17 draft for copy elision rules in C++ today, because in C++17 there is no copy elision at all for this example. The prvalue initializes the function argument, with no temporary involved so nothing that needs to be elided.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: _"Copy elision in C++ today means something that is allowed but not required by definition."_ Exactly my point. We are teaching here, so it would be best to be as clear as possible about that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Thanks - I edited your answer with the quotes from the standard you mentioned.

Comment: In everyday English "should" implies a strong recommendation, but not a strict requirement.  "must" is a strict requirement.   However, technical documentation often uses "should" or "shall" to mean a strict requirement.

Comment: @M.M I think in ISO standards only "shall" means a strict requirement, not "should".

Comment: @VittorioRomeo please don't add large chunks of copyrighted text to my answer.

Comment: @M.M I'm not aware of any technical documentation style that uses "should" as a strict requirement, see e.g. the ISO drafting guidelines, or [RFC 2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt), or http://reqexperts.com/blog/2012/10/using-the-correct-terms-shall-will-should/ or http://asq.org/standards-shall-should or http://etherealmind.com/requirements-terminology/ etc. etc.

Comment: Am I missing something? I thought a `std::string` object was of type `std::string`, not `std:string`.

Comment: @SeeOneRhino it was just a typo, obviously.

Answer (score 8):

> Where am I wrong?

An *rvalue reference* has the following form: `T&&`.

`decltype(string(""))` evaluates to `string`, not `string&&` - therefore it is not an *rvalue reference*.

```
is_same<decltype(string("Hello world!")), string>::value // true
```

---

> string("Hello world!") may be a rvalue but does not seem to be a "reference of any kind"

`string("Hello world!")` is an expression with *rvalue* value category - more specifically it is a *prvalue*. Expressions [are **non-references**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). *(More information: ["In C++, what expressions yield a reference type when decltype is applied to them?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241614/in-c-what-expressions-yield-a-reference-type-when-decltype-is-applied-to-them).)*

---

> Is there a way to get a true answer in case of a rvalue ?

You can use a transformation that:

- Given an *lvalue*, returns an *lvalue reference*.
- Given an *rvalue*, returns an *rvalue reference*.

The behavior mentioned above can be obtained thanks to [*template argument deduction rules*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction):

```
template <typename T>
using is_rvalue = std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>;

is_rvalue<decltype(string(""))>::value // true
is_rvalue<decltype(std::declval<string&&>())>::value // true
is_rvalue<decltype(std::declval<string&>())>::value // false
```

The code above works because:

- `T&&` is deduced as `T&&` both for *xvalues* and *prvalues*.
- `T&&` is deduced as `T&` otherwise *(i.e. for lvalues)*.

---

> Is there copy elision or not in his example ?

In C++14, the compiler **is allowed to** *(but not required)* to elide the copies in your example.

*(Credits to Jonathan Wakely for identifying the relevant C++14 standard draft quotes cited below.)*

Relevant C++14 standard draft *([N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf))* quotes:

- > **§12.8 [class.copy] p.31**
  >
  > When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
  >   object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object
  >   have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move
  >   operation as simply two different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of that object
  >   occurs at the later of the times when the two objects would have been destroyed without the optimization. This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which
  >   may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
  >
  > *[...]*
  >
  > > *[p.31.3]* when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference would be copied/moved
  > >     to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
  > >     constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move
- > **§5.2.2 [expr.call] p.4**
  >
  > When a function is called, each parameter shall be initialized with its corresponding
  >   argument. *[...]*  During
  >   the initialization of a parameter, an implementation may avoid the construction of extra temporaries by
  >   combining the conversions on the associated argument and/or the construction of temporaries with the
  >   initialization of the parameter. *[...]*

ISO/IEC. (2014). ISO International Standard ISO/IEC 14882:2014(E) – Programming Language C++. [Working draft]. Geneva, Switzerland: International Organization for Standardization (ISO). *(Retrieved from https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard)*

Comment: _"That is already in the standard and called std::forward"_ but then your example doesn't use std::forward

Comment: I think it is a bit misleading to just say "it is not a reference".  Expressions have a type (never a reference type) and a value category.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: whoops, I forgot to change that when I changed my approach *(I was using `std::forward` before)*. @M.M: hopefully it is more accurate now.