# Why the rvalue reference parameter cannot be passed between functions directly?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, rvalue, lvalue-to-rvalue, pass-by-rvalue-reference

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    void sendByRvalue(string&& str){
        cout << str << endl;
    }
};

class B{
private:
    A a;
    void send(string&& str){
        a.sendByRvalue(str);
    }
public:
    void run(const string& str){
        send("run " + str + "\n");
    } 
}; 

int main(void){
    string str("hello world");
    B b;
    b.run(str);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code shown above, I got some compile errors:
[image]

It seems that the `str` in `B::send` function has been changed to lvalue. Then I change the implement of `B::send`, like:

```
class B{
private:
    A a;
    void send(string&& str){
        cout << boolalpha << is_rvalue_reference<decltype(str)>::value << endl;
        a.sendByRvalue(std::move(str));
    }
public:
    void run(const string& str){
        send("run " + str + "\n");
    } 
};
```

Everything goes well, but the output of this program made me confuse more. The output is as follows:
[image]

Why the parameter str is a rvalue reference but I cannot pass it to the function `A::sendByRvalue` directly without `std::move` ?

Comment: Nice question. I'd suggest this though: For your compile errors it's better to have them in a written form so that others googling similar errors might find this question. To make it readable you can format it as a quote. For this question it doens't matter much, but it's a general rule on SO that the community dislikes pictures of text.

Comment: Good suggestion! Let others can find this question by googling the same error message is a good idea. I have tried to changed these messages to written format. But it looks strange. So I have little choice but to paste those pictures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str` is a named rvalue reference, which is treated in the language as an lvalue. rvalues are only xvalues or prvalues, and `str` is neither.

A note from [the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prop#basic.lval-2), on the xvalue rules:

> In general, the effect of this rule is that named rvalue references are treated as lvalues and unnamed rvalue references to objects are treated as xvalues; rvalue references to functions are treated as lvalues whether named or not.

```cpp
struct A {
int m;
};
A&& operator+(A, A);
A&& f();

A a;
A&& ar = static_cast<A&&>(a);
```

> The expressions `f()`, `f().m`, `static_­cast<A&&>(a)`, and `a + a` are xvalues. The expression `ar` is an lvalue.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. I got your point. The key point is that the rvalue reference and the rvalue is not the same thing. So that's why the `is_rvalue_reference<decltype(str)>::value` is true while the `str` is lvalue.

Answer (score 2):

I'll make a simpler example to explain

```cpp
void bar(std::string&& name) {
    std::cout << "Bar: " << name << std::endl;
}

void foo(std::string&& name) {
    bar(name);
}


int main() {
    foo("C++");
}
```

This is more or less the same as the example you have provided. Inside `foo()`, **`name` is an lvalue**. The temporary string  `C++`, which is an **rvalue** is passed into `name`. `name` is an lvalue. So the above code is basically translated to.

```cpp
void bar(std::string&& name) {
    std::cout << "Bar: " << name << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string foo{ "C++" };
    bar(foo);
}
```

Now it seems obvious where the problem is.

---

I wrote this simple program to help you understand better

```cpp
void foo(const std::string& name) {
    std::cout << "Passed as lvalue ref: " << name << std::endl;
}

void foo(std::string&& name) {
    std::cout << "Passed as rvalue ref: " << name << std::endl;
}
```

We'll use this function to call

```cpp
void bar(std::string&& name) {
    foo(name);
}

int main()  {
    bar("C++");
}
```

> Passed as lvalue ref: C++

This proves my point, now what if we use `std::move()`?

```cpp
void bar(std::string&& name) {
    foo(std::move(name));
}

int main()  {
    bar("C++");
}
```

> Passed as an rvalue ref: C++

If you want a simple way to check whether an expression is an lvalue or rvalue, you can try the below snippet

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_lvalue(T&) {
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_lvalue(T&&) {
    return false;
}
```

<sup>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296425/how-to-determine-programmatically-if-an-expression-is-rvalue-or-lvalue-in-c)</sup>