# How to determine programmatically if an expression is prvalue or lvalue or xvalue in C++?

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue, xvalue

The original question is here: [How to determine programmatically if an expression is rvalue or lvalue in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296425/how-to-determine-programmatically-if-an-expression-is-rvalue-or-lvalue-in-c)
My question is, we can already distinguish between lvalue and rvalue, so can we go further and distinguish between xvalue and prvalue?
My attempt is as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

#define IS_XVALUE(expr) (is_rvalue_reference<decltype((expr))>{})
#define IS_PRVALUE(expr) (!is_reference<decltype((expr))>{})
#define IS_LVALUE(expr) (is_lvalue_reference<decltype((expr))>{})

int main() {
  int a = 0;
  int &b = a;
  int &&c = 3;
  cout << IS_LVALUE(a);       // true
  cout << IS_LVALUE(b);       // true
  cout << IS_LVALUE(c);       // true
  cout << IS_PRVALUE(3);      // true
  cout << IS_XVALUE(move(a)); // true
}
```

It seems to be working correctly. But I'm not particularly confident.
Is my approach correct?
Is there a way to accomplish this without using macros？

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: "without using macros?" sure, just remove the macros and use the traits directly rather than the macros